# Convert date from weird string to date in format day month and year

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsdateformatter

Hi I am parsing an end point of API, from there I am getting a string which contain like this date string **2016-01-18T13:28:06.357** but I want to convert this like **01 Jan 16**, I have tried many times by using different format one of following mentioned. kindly need suggestion how to accomplish this task.

```
    NSString * date = [dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateformat date];
```

Comment: 2016-01-18T13:28:06.357 format is fix?

Comment: @kb920 Yes, this can't be change. this has to manage from mobile devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  // Objective C   
        NSString * date = [dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateformat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
        [dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
        NSDate *myDate = [dateformat dateFromString:date];

        [dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];

        NSString *strDate=[dateformat stringFromDate:myDate];

 // Swift 3.0
       var date = (dictionary["date"] as! String)
       var dateformat = DateFormatter()
       dateformat.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "EST")
       dateformat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
       var myDate = dateformat.date(fromString: date)!

       dateformat.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
       var strDate = dateformat.string(from: myDate)
```

Comment: I would recommend to avoid creating time zones using names like `EST` . It is very error-prone because the time zone names differ from language to language. Use `+[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this format:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2016-01-18T13:28:06.357";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
// date is 2016-01-18 08:28:06 +0000
```

And next convert that date to [format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) you need

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this :

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-01-18T13:28:06.357";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

// Convert date object into desired format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yy"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"newDateString=%@",newDateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this format code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    

//Get Date    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date is - %@",strDate);

//Get Month    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
NSString *strMonth = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Month is - %@",strMonth);

//Get Year    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString *strYear = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Year is - %@",strYear);
```

Log is :

```
Date is - 05
Month is - Feb
Year is - 2016
```

for set more format, [Click Me](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)